# How to find direction of velocity if there is balanced force?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

We know that when there is balanced force,there are two results that the system is at rest or moving with constant velocity. So how to find direction of velocity,as forces are equal and opposite .***Suppose a ball in a lift is in influence of balance forces.So how we decide it moves upward or download?***

Comment: Take careful note that even if the forces are not balanced what you learn from that is the direction of *acceleration* and there is no requirement that velocity and acceleration point in the same direction.

Comment: There is no acceleration as force is balanced .so we have to talk about constant velocity

Answer (score 1):

When the resultant force on a body becomes zero, Newton's 1st Law (the Law of Inertia) applies : the body continues in the state of uniform motion that it had immediately before the resultant force became zero. It continues moving in the same direction with the same speed.

Comment: That means if it starts in north and go to south so after it also moves towards south.so that type of questions are never asked to find the direction of motion if it does not give the direction from which it starts